# Call to undefined method FFMpeg\Media\Video::addWatermark()

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, laravel-8, ffmpeg-php

I m trying to add a watermark to a video that I have but it's giving me this error while applying a watermark

**The library is installed and working with the code commented but not when trying to add watermark**

```
use FFMpeg\FFMpeg;
use ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Filters\WatermarkFactory;
    
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open(public_path('video-making-test/test1.mp4'));
//    $video
//        ->filters()
//        ->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
//        ->synchronize();
//    $video
//        ->frame(\FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
//        ->save(public_path('video-making-test/results/frame.jpg'));
    $video->addWatermark(function(WatermarkFactory $watermark) {
    $watermark->fromDisk('public')
        ->open('video-making-test/logo.png')
        ->right(25)
        ->bottom(25);
});
```

Comment: Did you see this error at runtime or only during editing?

Comment: when i run this code it gives the error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use addWatermark(), you need to do according to the suggestion of @shingo.

However, If you persit to use FFMpeg\FFMpeg, try using watermark method instead:

```
$video
    ->filters()
    ->watermark($watermarkPath, array(
        'position' => 'relative',
        'bottom' => 50,
        'right' => 50,
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg` instead of `FFMpeg\FFMpeg`.

```
use ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg;

$video = FFMpeg::open(public_path('video-making-test/test1.mp4'));
$video->addWatermark(...);
```